# Delete printer which contain "EXAMPLE" in their name

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to build a PS script, to deletes all networkprinters which contain "EXAMPLE" in their name.

So far I have the following code:

```
Get–WMIObject Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq ‘true‘} | foreach{$_.delete()}
```

But this deletes every networkprinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Windows 7, you can still utilize WMI to delete the printers. Otherwise the other alternatives are using methods from the .Net classes `System.Printing` or `System.Drawing.Printing`. But it looks like you just need to and another filter in your where block

```
Get–WMIObject Win32_Printer | where{($_.Network -eq 'true') -and ($_.Name -like "*EXAMPLE*") } | foreach{$_.delete()}
```

Comment: nevermind, it works... I deleted the * my bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
# First check with -WhatIf, then remove -WhatIf when you are sure the command is targetting the right printer
Get-Printer | ?{ $_.Name.Contains("EXAMPLE") -and $_.Type -eq "Connection" } | Remove-Printer -Whatif
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
+ Get-Printer | ?{ $_.Name.Contains("EXAMPLE") -and $_.Type -eq "Connection" } | R ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-Printer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

My OS is win7 btw

Comment: @drifter213 Windows 7 doesn't have `Get-Printer` or `Remove-Printer`.

Comment: @BenH Contains is fine here? Since it is the static string method and not `-contains`

Comment: @Matt You are correct. Need to finish my coffee. The .Net String method Contains works fine in this case.

Comment: If you are on Windows 7, you can use wmi instead (as in your example), the logic would be the same.

Comment: @DavidBrabant But the command "get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | where{$_.Name.Contains("EXAMPLE") -and $_.Type -eq "Connection"} | foreach{$_.delete()}" does not work

Comment: @drifter213 `$_.Type -eq "Connection"` would be specific to the `get-printer` cmdlet. You want to you `$_.Network` like you did in your question.